# Suppose $A$ is symmetrical, prove that $B^TAB$ is symmetrical also.

Tags: linear-algebra

The only way I can think of proving this is with arbitrary constants, but we didn't have enough time on the test to prove such a large matrix, is there another faster way?

Comment: Well, what is about using the definition of symmetric matrix and apply it directly? Hint $(BA)^T=A^TB^T$.

Comment: Transpose of A equals A. Now take the transpose of the given one. It should be B^TA^TB. Then you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(B^TAB)^T=B^TA^TB=B^TAB$ since $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: I don't get it. How does it prove that $B^TAB = BAB^T$ (symmetry)? What about B being, say 6x3?

Comment: What you are saying is not the definition of a symmetric matrix, check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by Singular Value Decomposition. Symmetric matrices there are $$A=S\Sigma S^t$$We then do some algebra and substitutions:

$$B^tAB = B^tS\Sigma S^tB =\\ (subst.) / S^tB = C, B^tS = C^t/ \\= C^t\Sigma C$$ which is of same form as A if ($S=C^t$) and therefore also must be symmetric.